# Accessing from a class to a specifically controller hosted in another class

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha Touch app with the SlideToRemove plugin, but the issue is more simple..

I need to access from a individual class to other controller, because in the controller I have a important method and dependencies, How can I do this..? any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a few options:
1) Move this method to another helper class and call it from there
2) Fire an event when you need this method and handle it in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to call a method in a controller from a different controller? You can do

```
this.getApplication().getController('your_controller').yourControllerMethod();
```